# How can a perform a repeated measures ANOVA if assumptions aren't met + error message 0 (non-NA) cases?

Tags: r, anova

I hope one of you is able to give me some help with the correct statistical test for my data. I’ve been studying the effect of temperature on the physiology of large benthic foraminifera. Right now, I am analyzing my PAM data, so I have 3 variables

1. Yield; my response variable => a proportion between 0 and 1
2. Temperature; factor with 5 levels (33.1, 30.3, 24.4, 18.6 and 15.6 degrees Celsius)
3. Time; photosynthetic yield is measured over 4 weeks so Factor with 4 levels (T1, T2, T3 and T4)

So I have Yield ~ Temperature * Time (not sure yet if the interaction is significant because I can’t seem to find the right model to check this)

The data is highly left-skewed, the variance is not homogenous and my data contains some outliers but these are actual measurements. First I thought of transforming my data. So I tested the ascsine transformation (p'=arcsin[sqrt(p)]), square transformation (Y'=Ysq2) and the antilog transformation (Y'=e(sqY)). All of these transformation still don’t make the data normally distributed.

Since it’s proportion data, I was thinking of using a two-way ANOVA with binomial distribution, but I get underdispersion. When I correct for this using a quasibinomial, the “Residual deviance: 0.91405 on 80 degrees of freedom” stays exactly the same so it remains underdispersed.

```
model_binom <- glm(Yield ~ Temperature * Time, data=pam, binomial)
model_quasibinom <- glm(Yield ~ Temperature * Time, data=pam, quasibinomial(link="logit"))
```

Another thought I had was performing a Repeated Measures ANOVA because I measured the same pool of individuals over the different time points. But the assumptions aren’t met. However if I do continue trying to perform the test I get an error message.

```
res.aov <- anova_test(
data = pam, dv = Yield, wid = Vial,
within = c(Temperature, Time)
)
get_anova_table(res.aov)
```

*Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases* I've tried to solve this by adding another column "id" making it a factor, but this doesn't solve the problem.

I read there are no non-parametric alternatives to the two-way and the three-way repeated measures ANOVA.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how to properly analyze this data and which test to use in R? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Temperature and time are de facto continuously scaled. Why do you treat them as discrete factors?

Comment: Hi Danlooo, thanks for your question. I treated them as a factor because I wanted to carry out a two-way (repeated measures) ANOVA. Prior to the start of the experiment I already determined the 5 temperature categories and 4 different time points at which the measurements would be taken. Would you suggest something different?

Comment: ANOVA does not know that there are 0.2 degrees between 33.1 30.3 factors (not metric). ANOVA even doesn't know that  33.1 is bigger than 30.2 (not ordinal). Use correlation to assess the dependency between two numbers.

Comment: Another option, if these are documented as ordered factors is to use ordinal regression.